# convert Image to pcl using apacheFOP

Tags: java, apache-fop

I have a requirement that I want to convert GIF Image to PCL and print that pcl file from a specific tray from printer using Apach FOP. Can I have an example for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the following file:

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-fop/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/fop/FopOutputType.java#L0

```
    pdf("application/pdf"),
    ps("application/postscript"),
    pcl("application/x-pcl"),
    png("image/png"),
    jpeg("image/jpeg"),
    svg("image/svg+xml"),
    xml("application/X-fop-areatree"),
    mif("application/mif"),
    rtf("application/rtf"),
    txt("text/plain");

    private final String outputFormatExtended;

    FopOutputType(String outputFormatExtended) {
        this.outputFormatExtended = outputFormatExtended;
    }

    public String getFormatExtended() {
        return outputFormatExtended;
    }

    public static FopOutputType asFooOutputType(String outputFormatExtended) {
        if ("application/pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(outputFormatExtended)) {
            return pdf;
        } else if ("application/postscript".equalsIgnoreCase(outputFormatExtended)) {
            return ps;
        } else if ("application/x-pcl".equalsIgnoreCase(outputFormatExtended)) {
            return pcl;
        } else if ("image/png".equalsIgnoreCase(outputFormatExtended)) {
            return png;
        } else if ("image/jpeg".equalsIgnoreCase(outputFormatExtended)) {
            return jpeg;
        } else if ("image/svg+xml".equalsIgnoreCase(outputFormatExtended)) {
            return svg;
        } else if ("application/X-fop-areatree".equalsIgnoreCase(outputFormatExtended)) {
            return xml;
        } else if ("application/mif".equalsIgnoreCase(outputFormatExtended)) {
            return mif;
        } else if ("application/rtf".equalsIgnoreCase(outputFormatExtended)) {
            return rtf;
        } else if ("text/plain".equalsIgnoreCase(outputFormatExtended)) {
            return txt;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: [code example](http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=AQthbRGqhPHsPP82t50sTM5L0KY&cid=a1korI1KAvI&s=convert%20Image%20to%20pcl%20using%20apacheFOP&pp=0&fl=Java&ff=1&filterChecked=true&fp=499190&mp,=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&projSelected=true#L0)